# How to synchronize EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, autoscaling, aws-cloudformation

I created a web cluster using AWS's Cloudformation template.
The script installs Drupal 7. I connect an instance via ssh, delete Drupal 7 and install Drupal 6.
I want the other instances (and the instances will be created in the future) to inherit this modifies.
How could I achive this?

Answer (score 1):

This links is adresses my problem:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=321548